# How to send data from raspberry pi to windows (email)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I have finished my assignment with c language on raspberry pi, now l want to send it to my email in order to submit it.please l need help to how can do it.

Comment: How did you do your assignment if your PC is not connected to your Raspberry Pi? Or did you have a keyboard and monitor attached to the Raspberry Pi? Try saving the program on a USB memory stick formatted with FAT32 and then moving the memory stick to your PC.

Comment: I have done it with monitor.

Comment: Dropbox or similar service would work. You can run a mail server on the Pi that forwards through gmail https://samhobbs.co.uk/raspberry-pi-email-server

Comment: thank you @SteveRobillard,it worked .